# How I can rollback to previous version of deleted file on s3 via ruby aws-sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Any example how rollback to previous version of deleted file on s3 via ruby aws-sdk?

Looks like GEM aws-sdk-ruby not show deleted files in list of objects

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket('aws-sdk')
bucket.objects.each do |obj|
  if obj.key.start_with?("images/file_name.jpg")
    puts obj.to_yaml
  end
end
```

Comment: are you talking about versioned objects or actually deleting an object?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled versioning for my S3 bucket.

Comment: if the question is how to get previous versions of a file via ruby aws sdk, you can pass in a versionId is getObject: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_object-instance_method

Comment: Thanks, but how I can object "version_id" for deleted entry? I.e. I know key of deleted object and need re-store it, I see deleted object in web console, but need write script for re-store a bunch of files. "s3.get_object(bucket: 'my_bucket', key: 'images/12345/50x50.jpg') => Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist."

Comment: s3.get_object(bucket: 'my_bucket', key: 'images/12345/50x50.jpg', version_id: "yourversion")

Comment: How I can get "yourversion"? When I try fetch list of objects from S3, list not contain files that marked as deleted. I.e. files not exist and I want re-store them, so I need get previous version but not found a way for fetch that data.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_object_versions-instance_method

Comment: so to recap: if the object was deleted you need to figure out the version you want to retrieve. you can figure out what all the objects in the bucket with version are or the versions of a specific object. after that you use that to pass it in to get object

Comment: Yes, object was deleted. As I showed in my original question when I try get list of all object, that list dose not contain deleted files (bucket.objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can list previous versions like this:

```
    aws_versions = s3.client.list_object_versions(
      bucket: 'bucket_name',
      prefix: 'images/12345/50x50.jpg'
    ).versions
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#list_object_versions-instance_method

Download a necessary version like this:

```
    cache = s3.client.get_object(
      bucket: 'bucket_name',
      key: 'images/12345/50x50.jpg',
      version_id: 'your_version_id',
      response_target: Rails.root.join('tmp/images/12345/50x50.jpg')
    )
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_object-instance_method

And finally, save it to your model:

```
    model.attachment = Rails.root.join('tmp/images/12345/50x50.jpg').open
    model.save
```

PS: It's good to have paper_trail installed, so you could find the previous version prefix (the `images/12345/50x50.jpg` part) in model change history.